# python print first n lines of string

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate

I'm wondering how to print the first n lines of string in python
here is my code:

```
for word, numbers in enumerate(sorted):
        print(word,':',numbers)
```

The output looks like following. 
how can I print just first 10 lines of these string?
I've tried to use range, but it only prints True or False...

```
0 : ('the', 1577)
1 : ('and', 1080)
2 : ('of', 761)
3 : ('to', 734)
4 : ('a', 720)
5 : ('in', 550)
6 : ('it', 451)
7 : ('was', 432)
8 : ('his', 405)
9 : ('he', 381)
10 : ('I', 365)
11 : ('Scrooge', 361)
12 : ('that', 346)
13 : ('with', 312)
14 : ('you', 254)
15 : ('as', 229)
16 : ('said', 221)
17 : ('for', 209)
18 : ('had', 207)
19 : ('him', 198)
20 : ('not', 193)
```

Comment: Where is the string.?. Show us the string or the value in variable `sorted`

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get the output `0 : ('the', 1577)
1 : ('and', 1080)
2 : ('of', 761)
3 : ('to', 734)
4 : ('a', 720)
5 : ('in', 550)
6 : ('it', 451)
7 : ('was', 432)
8 : ('his', 405)
9 : ('he', 381)` .?

Comment: @SreeramTP Yes!!

Comment: @SreeramTP The variable sorted looks like [('the', 1577), ('and', 1080), ('of', 761), ('to', 734), ('a', 720), ('in', 550), ('it', 451), ('was', 432), ('his', 405), ('he', 381), ('I', 365), ('Scrooge', 361), ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the 10 first elements of the list then just slice the list accordingly

```
for word, numbers in enumerate(sorted[:10]):
        print(word,':',numbers)
```

Comment: Note that slicing a list just for iteration, although concise and readable, is less efficient because slicing needs to create a new list and copy the items to the new list. Use `itertools.islice` if you want to slice efficiently for the purpose of iteration.

Answer (score 11):

For those who came to this post for the title and not the OP's question (which is not so related to the question).

For a one-liner we could split() the string by newlines and then join() first N elements of the resulting list by newlines again.

```
os.linesep.join(str.split(os.linesep)[:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` statement to `break` the loop once `word`, your counter variable as generated by `enumerate`, reaches `10`:

```
for word, numbers in enumerate(sorted):
    if word == 10:
        break
    print(word,':',numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment that you need the output

```
0 : ('the', 1577) 1 : ('and', 1080) 2 : ('of', 761) 3 : ('to', 734) 4 : ('a', 720) 5 : ('in', 550) 6 : ('it', 451) 7 : ('was', 432) 8 : ('his', 405) 9 : ('he', 381)
```

You can break the loop after 10 iterations like this.

```
count = 0
for word, numbers in enumerate(sorted):
    if count == 10:
        break
    print(word,':',numbers)
    count += 1
```

Or

You can make use of the `word` and break on the base of that like this

```
for word, numbers in enumerate(sorted):
    if word == 10:
        break
    print(word,':',numbers)
```

Keep in mind that it is not a best practice to use reserved keywords as variable names. So, you must be using some other variable name instead of `sorted`

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked with this:

```
for key, value in(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(0))[:10]):
print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

i used slices on my sorted method.